# How to create relocatable Apps

Tags: macos, rpath

hope someone can help me. I have something programed in python. That uses a lot of libraries. 
So I created a virtual environment with virtualenv and copied every file is needed in this environment. Then I used Platypus to create an .app. Of corse the app isn't working, because if you use otool -L on a .so or .dylib then the linking points to the original install location. Know I can use install_name_tool and set the new absolute path, the app works now, but is not relocatable. After a bit reading I find out, that you can set -rpath for Mac OS X 10.5+.  So I changed the paths to @rpath/lib/...dylib and startet the app with

```
-rpath @loader_path/../Resources/virt1
```

But it isn't working. So I'm missing something or doing something wrong?