# SDL App won't open unless Framework is installed in /Library/Frameworks

Tags: xcode, macos, sdl, xcode3, sdl-1.2

I have built a very simple app with Xcode 3.1.4 on OSX 10.8.

It starts in 10.8 *if* I have SDL.Framework installed in `/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework`. (SDL 1.2.15 from the SDL site.)

I also tried it in another Mac, with OSX 10.9. It doesn't work there either, with the same error message:

```
Process:         SDLOpenGLIntro [591]
Path:            /Volumes/*/SDLOpenGLIntro.app/Contents/MacOS/SDLOpenGLIntro
Identifier:      com.yourcompany.SDLOpenGLIntro
Version:         ???
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [255]
Responsible:     SDLOpenGLIntro [591]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-10-22 19:40:49.818 +0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  D0DA6FFA-AC63-8F0E-4FE5-B907EEFA8638


Crashed Thread:  0

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL
  Referenced from: /Volumes/*/SDLOpenGLIntro.app/Contents/MacOS/SDLOpenGLIntro
  Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
0x8fe81000 - 0x8feb3417  dyld (239.4) <0F2176BD-4239-3506-BA41-3B885269520E> /usr/lib/dyld

Model: MacBookPro9,2, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B08, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.5 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.2f44
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353737334448302D434B302020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353737334448302D434B302020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.7f3 14616, 3 services, 15 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: ST1000LM014-1EJ164, 1 TB
Serial ATA Device: OPTIARC DVD RW AD-5970H
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

I have tried to find an answer on Stack Overflow and other sites, but can't make any suggestion so far work.

I have tried for instance to run this script after the app is created:

```
#!/bin/sh

APP="${1?}"

echo "Copying SDL"
cp -r "/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework" "${APP}/Contents/Frameworks/"

echo "Changing package identification of SDL"
install_name_tool -id \
        @rpath/../Frameworks/SDL.framework/SDL \
        "${APP}/Contents/Frameworks/SDL.framework/SDL"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022247/rpath-for-a-dynamic-library-embedded-in-a-framework/13058295#13058295 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368753/how-to-create-relocatable-apps https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-06-linking-and-install-names.html https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/developertools/conceptual/DynamicLibraries/000-Introduction/Introduction.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534208/sdl-app-wont-open-unless-framework-is-installed-in-system http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859718/bundle-cant-find-copied-framework-from-xcode

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713519/os-x-xcode-how-to-bundle-a-framework-into-a-dynamic-library http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191681/xcode-creating-universal-frameworks-as-dependents-of-a-universal-framework